# Can we update a record that is defined as a foreign key of a unique record define in a different table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am new to PostgreSQL and how i can update the records while they are related with a foreign key definition.
I am getting an error and that would be great if you can guide me with any hints
Let's say we have two different tables like below :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student
(
    id_num        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL REFERENCES registered(student_id),
    first_name             VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    last_name              VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    birthdate              DATE NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(id_num)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS registered
(
    student_id        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    paid_tuition             BOOL NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY(paid_tuition)
);
```

Based on my understating i need to fill the registered table and then try to insert values to the student table that their id match the student_id value in  registered table.
But when I try it I get the following error?

Any idea or recommendation?

> Message:"update or delete on table "registered" violates foreign key
> constraint "student_id_num_id_fkey" on table "student"",
> Detail:"Key (id_num)=(idNum-1) is still referenced from table
> "student".", Hint:"", Position:0, InternalPosition:0,
> InternalQuery:"", Where:"", SchemaName:"", TableName:"student",
> ColumnName:"", DataTypeName:"",
> ConstraintName:"student_id_num_id_fkey", File:"ri_triggers.c",
> Line:2490, Routine:"ri_ReportViolation"}

Comment: You are trying to delete a record/update student_id field table `registered` which is already exist in student table. RDBMS will prevent you to do this.

Comment: Thanks @AkhileshMishra, i basically try to fill out the registered table first not deleting any record to it. This is my assumption that without adding the student_id and using the same ones when trying to create student table will cause an issue

Comment: @AkhileshMishra thanks i figured it out that there is an initializer function which is called in which the related fields are deleted in an inappropriate order. after fixing the order the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you are linking tables in opposite direction , to me it makes more sense that "registered" table has been linked to student table by fk studentid .
also in your "student" table definition you are saying that column "id" is primary key while no "id" column has been declared.

so here is what I mean:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student
(
    id_num        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL REFERENCES registered(student_id),
    first_name             VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    last_name              VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    birthdate              DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_num)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS registered
(
    student_id        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL REFERENCES student(id_num)
    paid_tuition             BOOL NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_num)
);
```

Comment: thanks, I just made an example to ask my question. 
But i hear you.
Also update the primary key section in question